# How to set class path variable for two tomcat?

Tags: java

I am using two tomcat for deploying two different applications. Both are having different directory.If i set classpath for one than its startup.bat is working fine. But when i try to set for another tomcat path in the same variable, both startup.bat are not working.

Comment: What kind of errors do you face, Are  you using different ports for your tomcat ?

Comment: yes. i am using two tomcat with two different ports. I used to start it with startup.bat but both are just flashing a window.

Comment: Can you send error ?

Comment: The window closes because an error. Start tomcat from command line, so you can see what's happening. Then edit your question and post more info.

Comment: okay.................

Answer (score 1):

You should use different http port for each tomcat instance

Comment: i am using different ports.

Comment: When i try to start startup.bat, the cmd window is just get flashed and get close. No errors. :-(